# accessing dictionary data from jinja template

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have a `dictionary` in my views and want to render all of it's data in my frontend.

my `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    leafVsImdtParents = {
        100: [{'childId': 1, 'childStructure': 'Leaf'}, {'childId': 2, 'childStructure': 'Intermediate'}],
        200: [{'childId': 3, 'childStructure': 'Intermediate'}, {'childId': 4, 'childStructure': 'Leaf'}],
        300: [{'childId': 5, 'childStructure': 'Leaf'}, {'childId': 6, 'childStructure': 'Intermediate'}],
        400: [{'childId': 7, 'childStructure': 'Intermediate'}, {'childId': 8, 'childStructure': 'Leaf'}],
    }
    return render(request,'index.html', {'leafVsImdtParents ': leafVsImdtParents })
```

In my `templete`:

```
<tbody>
    {% for key, value in leafVsImdtParents %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {% if key != 0 %}
            <a href="{% url 'diagnosis:ruleTree' ruleId=key %}" class="text-dark fw-bolder text-hover-primary d-block fs-6">
                <span class="badge badge-light-info fs-7"> {{ key }} </span>
            </a>
            {% else %}
            <span class="badge badge-light-danger"> Root Node! </span>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% for j in value %}
            <a href="">
                {% if j.childStructure == 'Leaf' %}
                <span class="badge badge-light-success fs-7"> {{ j.childId }} </span>
                {% else %}
                <span class="badge badge-light-info fs-7"> {{ j.childId }} </span>
                {% endif %}
            </a>
            {% endfor %}
            
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

But it shows error like:

```
ValueError at /ruleTreeGroup/
Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.
```

Please suggest how can I solve fix this and how to access all the data from `data` dictionary in my frontend

Comment: What is `leafVsImdtParents`…‽

Comment: loop should be `leafVsImdtParents.items`, you are expecting two values key, value but looping over dict without `items` will return key only

Comment: It shows error like: `Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'leafVsImdtParents.items()'`

Comment: there will be no parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
<tbody>
    {% for key, value in leafVsImdtParents.items %} # this line is changed
    <tr>
        <td>
            {% if key != 0 %}
            <a href="{% url 'diagnosis:ruleTree' ruleId=key %}" class="text-dark fw-bolder text-hover-primary d-block fs-6">
                <span class="badge badge-light-info fs-7"> {{ key }} </span>
            </a>
            {% else %}
            <span class="badge badge-light-danger"> Root Node! </span>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% for j in value %}
            <a href="">
                {% if j.childStructure == 'Leaf' %}
                <span class="badge badge-light-success fs-7"> {{ j.childId }} </span>
                {% else %}
                <span class="badge badge-light-info fs-7"> {{ j.childId }} </span>
                {% endif %}
            </a>
            {% endfor %}
            
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```